# Fonts wont update neither in emulator nor in real device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android programming, and I encountered beginners error.

Version: Android Studio 3.2.1
Chosen login activity.xml
When I Add image and change background of login activity to this image, image is applied.
I have trouble with textHints - they wont change, they are red all the time.

As seen in the image - white is set

[image]

But textHints are still red

[image]

I tried cold boot, connect my own device, uncheck Instant Run, delete and recreate project. Nothing helped.
OS: WIndows 10, Android Studio installed on C:\

Project saved in C:\User\etc

Comment: If you didn't use the img, what's the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define an item in your styles.xml. As an example, for blue:

```
<item name="android:textColorHint">#303F9F</item>
```

Also call your theme in
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Base">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


<!--Splash Activity Theme-->
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>


<!--Theme Base MATERIAL-->
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#303F9F</item>
    ...
```

Comment: One more question I would like to ask, why when I change something via Design tab, its not applied in the Emulator ?

Comment: this method has no effect for me

Comment: Have you define your custom theme in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I edited my answer and added "using theme" example. I hope it helps.